# html5 streaming vs red5

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, red5

I'm developing a streaming website and I'm currently using the video tag with html5 and it works fine but in terms of bandwidth is sucks a lot and I'm wondering if using a streaming service like red5 or equivalent I will fix the bandwidth issue.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming vs any kind of full download will save you bandwidth in the long run; especially if you have people that are not watching an entire clip. You don't need red5 specifically for this and its not compatible with html5 out-of-the-box; you'd have to get a plugin or write your own. I hope that helps.